# How can I get calendar date and time to as per user timezone

Tags: java

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
    cal.setTime(new Date());

    System.out.println("cal:"+cal);
    System.out.println("cal.getime:"+cal.getTime());
```

output are:

`cal:java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1325177592164,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="PST",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=PST,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2011,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=53,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=29,DAY_OF_YEAR=363,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=0,HOUR=8,HOUR_OF_DAY=8,MINUTE=53,SECOND=12,MILLISECOND=164,ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
cal.getime:Thu Dec 29 22:23:12 IST 2011`

Problems facing:

1. While print 'cal' object getting date and time as per time zone.
2. `cal.getTime()` not displaying date and time to as per timezone.

Answer (score 2):

You should represent time in UTC (java.util.Date) and then display the time in the local timezone of the user. Use `DateFormat` and `TimeZone` to do that. [Read this article](http://www.devrecipes.com/2010/02/14/datetimetimezone-manipulation-and-conversion-in-java-a-few-examples/) for more details

Comment: the link is not available

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Date object always display time in GMT. You need to use something like SimpleDateFormat to display time in formatted timezone.

Answer (score 0):

assign user given time into string variable then create date formatter. then parse the given string using date formatter.

> String dateAndTime = "30-12-2011 12:00:00 GMT+5.30"; dateFormate
>   formate = new SimpleDateFormate("dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss z"); Date date =
>   formate.parse(dateAndTime );

Answer (score 0):

Date object is Java doesn't store the TimeZone info.
If you do

```
new Date()
```

this is the current local time of the machine/jvm.

To print it with the default/local timezone info:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```